# Reading an XLSX file in Azure File Storage

Tags: azure-storage

I need to read an Excel file that is located in a folder in Azure File Storage. This is not in blob storage.
I cannot download the file to a local drive, since there is none.
I cannot seem to get started on how to access the file or read it in place.
Can someone help to get me started?
thanks

Comment: Are you using any SDK?

Comment: not yet, not sure where to begin. was looking at Azure.Storage

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.shares-readme#download-a-file. HTH.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what i was looking for! I will post the end result code

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic code that works!

```
    ShareClient share = new ShareClient(connectionString, shareName);
    ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(dirName);
    ShareFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient(filename);
    OpenSettings openSettings = new OpenSettings();

    using (Stream stream = file.OpenRead())
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, false, openSettings))
        {
            readRow();
        }
    }
```